# How to change markers shape manually in plotly interactive plot

Tags: python, plotly

I am trying to assign different markers for different colors in plotly interactive plot. By using the following script I can get the interactive plot, can change the size of the markers 'o', can annotate the text. Plotly plot I got is attached. I want to change the markers as in PCA plot attached.[image: plotly_plot][image: PCA plot]

**#SCRIPT**

```
import plotly 
import plotly.plotly as py
from plotly.graph_objs import Scatter
import plotly.graph_objs as go
plotly.tools.set_credentials_file(username='XXX', api_key='XXXX')
#py.plot(data, filename = 'basic-line', auto_open=True, Transforms = 'Split')

trace1 = Scatter(
    x=x1,           # x-coordinates of trace
    y=y1,          # y-coordinates of trace
    mode='markers + text',   # scatter mode
    text = label1, textposition='top center',
    marker = dict(size = 15, color = color_3),
     textfont=dict(
        color='black',
        size=18,
        family='Times New Roman'
     )

    )

layout = {
    'xaxis': {
        'showticklabels': False,
        'showgrid': False,
        'zeroline': False,
    },
    'yaxis': {
        'showticklabels': False,
        'showgrid': False,
        'zeroline': False,
    }
}
data = [trace1]

fig = {
    'data': data,
    'layout': layout,
}

py.plot(fig, filename='example1')
```

I have changed the color of the scatter points manually, I have a list of colors (color_3). I can assign a marker for each color say marker_list. But how can I use this marker_list in plotly to obtain the plot similar to PCA plot attached? While doing PCA plot I added it in ax.scatter, see a snippet below:

```
for i in range(len(marker_list)):
    ax.scatter(x1[i], y1[i], color = color_3[i], s=150, marker=marker_list[i], alpha=0.8, edgecolors='none')
```

Can I use the same list of marker somewhere in the above script to get an interactive plotly plot? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**Updated**
After Iljas suggestions and by using names from the list instead of the number. I got the following plot, a type I was looking for.
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "interactive plotly plot"? Kind of drop-down, where you can select the marker-type per category?

Comment: I mean I can zoom in or out by selecting some regions of this plot. I need to know where I can use the marker-type ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can set the shape of the markers with the `symbol` attribute, e.g.:

```
trace1 = Scatter(
    x=x1,           # x-coordinates of trace
    y=y1,          # y-coordinates of trace
    mode='markers + text',   # scatter mode (more in UG section 1)
    text = label1, textposition='top center',
    marker = dict(size = 15, color = color_3, symbol = 'cross'), # Add symbol here!
     textfont=dict(
        color='black',
        size=18,
        family='Times New Roman'
     )
```

An overview of different shapes can be found inside the [docs](https://plot.ly/python/reference/#box-marker-symbol)

Of course you can also pass a list of different shapes by class, like you did with the color.

Comment: I tried it before but my mistake was  I used numbering from the list instead of names for the marker. What do those numbers suggest?  Thanks for pointing me to the exact point and think about it.

Comment: You are absolutely right, you can use numbers as a substitute for the symbol names. Maybe your input was a string (`symbol = '100'` -- doesn’t work) instead of an integer (`symbol = 100` -- should work)?